# Case in the Group By clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

First post on here.

The query below runs OK and is getting me the figures i need. The problem is that I must have the `oh.paid` column in the `GROUP BY` clause for the query to run. This gives me two results per `oh.unitname`, I would only like one.

I have searched around and have found some related problems but the solutions didn't work on my query.

Hope some friendly souls out there can point me in the correct direction.

```
    SELECT oh.unitname,
   oh.CostCode,
   CASE
      WHEN oh.Paid = 1
       THEN 'Kr '+CONVERT( VARCHAR(50), CAST(SUM(oh.paidsum * oh.ExchangeRate) AS MONEY), -1)
       ELSE 'Kr '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(SUM(oh.totalprice * oh.ExchangeRate) AS MONEY), -1)
   END AS Price
    FROM dbo.OrderHead oh
    WHERE oh.RowDeleted = 0
  AND oh.UnitName LIKE '%%'
  AND oh.DateCreated >= '2016-01-01'
  AND oh.DateCreated < '2016-12-30'
  AND oh.CostCode = 1
  GROUP BY oh.UnitName,
     oh.CostCode,
     oh.Paid
  ORDER BY oh.UnitName;
```

Comment: Do you want one or two sum's in the result?

Comment: Do you have multiple rows, one with oh.paid = 1 and other/s with oh.paid <> 1?

Comment: Hi, the oh.paid column have 1 if paid and then 0 if not paid. i would like to sum the two to get a total paid and not paid...hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT oh.unitname, oh.CostCode,
       ('Kr ' +
        CONVERT( VARCHAR(50), CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN oh.PAID = 1 THEN oh.paidsum * oh.ExchangeRate ELSE 0 END) AS MONEY), -1)
       ) as PaidSum,
       ('Kr ' +
        CONVERT( VARCHAR(50), CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN oh.PAID <> 1 THEN oh.paidsum * oh.ExchangeRate ELSE 0 END) AS MONEY), -1)
       ) as NotPaidSum
FROM dbo.OrderHead oh
WHERE oh.RowDeleted = 0 AND
      oh.UnitName LIKE '%%' AND
      oh.DateCreated >= '2016-01-01' AND
      oh.DateCreated < '2016-12-30'
      oh.CostCode = 1
GROUP BY oh.UnitName, oh.CostCode,
ORDER BY oh.UnitName;
```

This splits the sums into two columns.  It assumes that `oh.Paid` is not `NULL`.  If that is possible, it is easy to modify the second condition.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. just tried your query but its not what i needed. i want to sum the "PaidSum" and "NotPaidSum".

Comment: @Tommel . . . Then just keep that column and not the other.

Comment: i see can see how you would misunderstand my comment above. The query you helped me with produce two values, i only need to sum these two values now.

Comment: unitname CostCode   PaidSum                  NotPaidSum
xxx Unitn 1            Kr 26,209,880.79          Kr 11,169,950.00

Comment: thanks for your assistance you pointed me in the right direction. added a third column with Int as datatype to sum the two together.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2 values to be converted to one would you want to SUM them? If so try this:

```
select a.Unitname,a.CostCode, SUM(a.Price) as Price
from
(
SELECT oh.unitname,
oh.CostCode,
CASE
  WHEN oh.Paid = 1
   THEN 'Kr '+CONVERT( VARCHAR(50), CAST(SUM(oh.paidsum * oh.ExchangeRate) AS MONEY), -1)
   ELSE 'Kr '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(SUM(oh.totalprice * oh.ExchangeRate) AS MONEY), -1)
END AS Price
FROM dbo.OrderHead oh
WHERE oh.RowDeleted = 0
AND oh.UnitName LIKE '%%'
AND oh.DateCreated >= '2016-01-01'
AND oh.DateCreated < '2016-12-30'
AND oh.CostCode = 1
)
GROUP BY a.UnitName,
 a.CostCode
ORDER BY a.UnitName
```

This will allow you to sum the paid column after the initial changes done in the case statement.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

May be because for some of your oh.unitname and/or oh.costname the oh.paid is different. So it will group for paid =1 separate and else separate